# How to align <li> elements on one axis in <ul>?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I have created ul element. These are html and css for my navigation bar:

Html:

```
    <ul id="list-nav">
<li><a href="index.html"><img src="http://s20.postimg.org/w5uddizg9/small.png"></a>

</li>
<li><a href="Marsrutas.html">Maršrutas</a>

</li>
<li><a href="Nuotraukos.html">Nuotaukos</a>

</li>
<li><a href="Apie zygi.html">Apie žygį</a>

</li>
<li><a href="Apie mane.html">Apie mane</a>

</li>
<li><a href="Dviraciai.html">Dviračiai</a>

</li>
<li><a href="Kontaktai.html">Kontaktai</a>

</li>
```

CSS:

```
            ul#list-nav {
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:525px;
}
ul#list-nav li {
    display:inline text-align: center;
}
ul#list-nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:auto;
    color:#eee;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
ul#list-nav li a {
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
ul#list-nav li a:hover {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bufbond/6hPLK/3/)

As you can see, all li elements are aligned to top of the page. Is there any way to align them on [one axis](http://s20.postimg.org/ijy8yq77h/axis.jpg)?

(Sorry if I made some grammar mistakes english is not my native language)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6hPLK/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/6hPLK/7/

```
   ul#list-nav {
        margin:auto;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        width:525px;
        display:block;
    }
    ul#list-nav li {
        display:inline;
       text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    ul#list-nav li a {
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:5px 0;
        width:auto;
        color:#eee;    
        margin:5px;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    ul#list-nav li a img {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

removed float from anchors and used display:inline-block. Added `vertical-align:middle` to image,li and anchors

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
ul#list-nav {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 525px;
    display: table;
    }

ul#list-nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This will make it to align in one-axis as you need :)

What it does?

I have added `table` to the `ul` and `table-cell` to the `li`. So that the list items are aligned on the same axis. `vertical-align: bottom` is used to mention the axis.

Am little confused with one-axis you have mentioned in the question. In case you wanted to show the list items on the middle, then use `vertical-align: middle`. So it means that this code will help you to customize easily as you wish by just changing the vertical alignment :)